# URL en Angular Production No se pueden introducir URL manualmente ni redirecciona correctamente

Tags: angular, url, server

**INTRODUCCIÓN**

Intento que una app de Angular en producción funcione en el servidor (Apache preferiblemente o nginx), La ruta es localhost/gmapps/

**PROBLEMA**

- Al intentar hacer login o logout da un error 500. Después del error, vuelvo a la URL localhost/gmapps/ y veo que se ha logueado /deslogueado con éxito.
- También da el mismo error cuando escribo una URL manualmente. Por ejemplo, si accedo a una opción llamada contenedores en la app, la url pone localhost/gmapps/contenedores y accede normal. Pero si escribo la palabra contendedores en la URL, me da el error 500.

Intuyo que el error va relacionado a la administración de URL en Angular.

**CÓDIGO RELACIONADO**

**Cuando accedo a través del login tenemos esto:**

```
onLogin(form: NgForm): void {
    if(!this.authService.checkLogin()){
      this.authService.login(form.value).subscribe(
        res => {
          /* let redirect = this.authService.redirectUrl
            ?  "/"
            : "/"; */
          /* console.log("Login.component.onLogin.redirect:"+ redirect); */

          this.router.navigateByUrl("/").then(()=>{
            window.location.reload(); //he puesto esto para que se refresque la info
            console.log("login component onlogin navigatebyurl inicio");
          });
      });
    }
  }
```

**y en auth.service.ts tenemos:**

```
login(user: UserI): Observable<JwtResponseI>{
  return this.httpClient.post<JwtResponseI>(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/login`,
  user).pipe(tap(
    (res:JwtResponseI)=>{
      if(res){
        let currentU ={
          name: res.dataUser.name,
          email: res.dataUser.email,
          role: res.dataUser.role,
          id: res.dataUser.id,
          avatar: res.dataUser.avatar,
          signature: res.dataUser.signature
        };
        //guardar token
      this.saveToken(res.dataUser.accessToken, res.dataUser.expiresIn, currentU);

      }
    },error =>{console.log(error);}
  ));
}
```

**Ahora nos vamos al backend. Por un lado tenemos:**

```
const Users = require('./auth.controller');
module.exports = (router)=>{
    router.post('/registro', Users.createUser);
    router.post('/login', Users.loginUser);
    router.post('/updateuser', Users.updateuser);
}
```

**y Users.loginUser lleva a**

```
exports.loginUser = (req,res,next)=>{
    const UserData = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }
    User.findOne({$or:[{email: UserData.email},{name: UserData.email}]},(err,user)=>{
        if (err) return res.status(500).send('No se encuentra el usuario.');
        if (!user){
            // email does not exist
            res.status(409).send({message: 'Este usuario no existe.'});
        } else {
            const resultPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(UserData.password, user.password);
            if (resultPassword){
                const expiresIn = 14*60*60;
                const accessToken = jwt.sign({id: user.id, role:user.role}, SECRET_KEY, {expiresIn: expiresIn});
                const dataUser = {
                    id: user.id,
                    name: user.name,
                    email: user.email,
                    accessToken: accessToken,
                    expiresIn: expiresIn,
                    role: user.role,
                    avatar: user.avatar,
                    signature: user.signature
                }
                res.send({dataUser});
            }else{
                //password wrong
                res.status(409).send({message: 'La constraseña no coincide.'});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Nota**: el error 500 del que hablamos no es el presentado en el código 'No se encuentra el usuario.'.

No obstante, sospecho que esto es un problema de la configuración de angular y la forma de administrar las URL.

He probado con dos servidores: Apache y uno llamado nginx. Ambos actúan de la misma forma, dan error en los mismos sitios. Pero uno me lanza un 500 y el otro un 404.
(NOTA: En versión dev (ponemos "ng serve" en el cli) no existe problema pese a estar conectado al servidor donde están almacenados los usuarios. Igual el problema va más en relación a la versión prod (ponemos "ng build --prod" en cli) al estar almacenada en apache o nginx).

Tengo el .htaccess de ejemplo en los docs de angular para apache. ([Fallback configuration examples](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)) pero el problema persiste.
También he probado otra configuración recomendada llamada [HashLocationStrategy](https://medium.com/wineofbits/angular-2-routing-404-page-not-found-on-refresh-a9a0f5786268), y tampoco he logrado arreglarlo.

He preguntado en stackoverflow sin éxito y he solicitado ayuda online, tampoco han sabido ayudarme.
Si necesitan más trozos de código no dudéis en pedirlo.

Comment: Varias cosas: "usuario no encontrado" -> Error 401, no 500. El estado 500 significa "fallo en el servidor", que es lo que parece que estás teniendo. Si tienes un error 500 que no has previsto, mira los logs de Node para averiguar qué está fallando.

Comment: Por otro lado, lo de meter una URL a mano y que falle, es un tema distinto. No sé cómo tienes montado el servidor, si usáis un proxy inverso o no, pero algo está mal configurado